# Remove everything after 3rd space

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula which removes everything after the 2nd space. I want to alter the formula so it removes text after 3rd space.

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(" ",X13,FIND(" ",X13,1)+1)),X13,LEFT(X13,FIND(" ",X13,FIND(" ",X13,1)+1)))
```

Answer (score 3):

It's shorter to substitute the third space with some symbol that shouldn't appear in the text like a pipe symbol "|" then use find

```
=LEFT(X13,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(X13," ","|",3)))
```

Comment: Seems far better formula than mine.

Comment: Thanks! But mine does rely on finding a symbol that doesn't appear in the text so isn't completely general, but you could use multiple characters I think.

Comment: Some weird combination of characters can be used e.g "|:)" :) 

I usually use a lot of nested `FIND`s leading to very complicated formulas.  Nice trick

Answer (score 1):

Change the third argument in your `FIND` formula to the position of the second space + 1

Modified your formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(" ",X13,FIND(" ",X13,FIND(" ",X13,1)+1)+1)),X13,LEFT(X13,FIND(" ",X13,FIND(" ",X13,FIND(" ",X13,1)+1)+1)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Another formula:

```
=LEFT(X13,FIND(" ",X13,FIND(" ",X13,FIND(" ",X13)+1)+1))
```

Drag/Copy down as required. See image for reference.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for help, i was on the same path. I was trying to insert the 3rd find just i did not understand that i had to add   +2)+2))  as formula itself =FIND(" ",X13,1)